# How to Wowza server Integrate with my .net Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need help to develop Internet radio kind of application, where I can have multiple channels and I can stream mp3 files constantly. I want to integrate wowza server with my .net web application from where I can manage play list and send stream to wowza server from where my users can listen it.
Can anyone please help me to find correct flow? Also I need some sample code /applications from where I can find some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this link and follow step
http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?625-How-to-get-started-as-a-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-Manager-administrator#signinManager